# JSP custom tags not working in Tomcat 8.0

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jsp-tags

I cannot seem to get JSP custom tags working in my JSPX 2.1 project using Tomcat 8 for love nor money, using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers 4.4.1, testing in Firefox 35.0.1  Windows 8.1.

Symptoms: There are no error messages, they are simply passed over and the tag is not processed, as my print statements inside it for debugging simply aren't executed. In-built JSTL tags work with no fuss.

After banging my head against the wall for a while, I moved on and tried another custom tag. This also didn't work, same symptoms.

Things I have tried:
I have compared my code with a pre-built example web project from a book - custom tags in this project are called and execute normally, so I suspect this is something to do with project config - what though I don't know, a trawl through the properties page in Eclipse didn't show any obvious differences.
I have also compared web.xml config and .tld config from the aforementioned example, adjusting their version numbers and .xsd references to be the same in case this was the issue.
I have looked at similar issues and they related to build dependencies on Tomcat 7 in Maven specifically, I have checked the dependencies of these projects specifically, and believe they are the same.

.tld file (within WEB-INF directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd ">
<description>Auctioneers custom tags</description>
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>dauct</short-name>
<tag>
    <description>Create a user</description>
    <display-name>createUser</display-name>
    <name>createUser</name>
    <tag-class>derbyauct.users.UserInsertTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>user</name>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>derbyauct.users.UserCreation</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <description>Returns auctions at status ready</description>
    <display-name>returnReadyAuctions</display-name>
    <name>returnReadyAuctions</name>
    <tag-class>derbyauct.auctions.NextAuctionTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
</tag>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.5">
      <display-name>auctioneers</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
            <display-name>AuctServlet</display-name>
            <servlet-name>AuctServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>auct.AuctServlet</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
        <param-name>base</param-name>
        <param-value>/dauct</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>imageURL</param-name>
        <param-value>/images/</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>jdbcDriver</param-name>
        <param-value>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/derbyauct</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>dbUserName</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
      </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuctServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dauct/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Tag handler

```
package auct.users;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import auct.utils.DALManager;
import auct.users.UserCreation;

public class UserInsertTag extends TagSupport {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserCreation user;

    public UserCreation getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserCreation user) {
        this.user = user;
        System.out.println("user object :" + user);
    }

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
        DALManager dm = (DALManager)context.getAttribute("dalManager");
        try {
            dm.insertUser(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

JSPX file calling tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:dauct="urn:jspltd:/WEB-INF/tlds/dauct.tld"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    version="2.3"
>
<jsp:directive.page 
    language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
<jsp:text>
    <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
<c:url var="cssUrl" value="/css/dauct.jspx"/>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>User</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssUrl}" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="TopMenu.jspx" flush="true"/>
<jsp:include page="LeftMenu.jspx" flush="true"/>
<div class="content">
  <h2>Registration Complete</h2>
  <jsp:useBean id="user" class="auct.users.UserCreation" scope="request"/>
  <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user"/>
 <dauct:createUser user="${user}"/>
      <p class="info">
        Thank you for registering.<br/>
        Welcome to Auctioneers <c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>
        </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

lib folder

```
annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-storeconfig.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
ecj-4.4.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
jsp-api.jar
list.txt
mariadb-java-client-1.1.8.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-jni.jar
tomcat-spdy.jar
tomcat-util-scan.jar
tomcat-util.jar
tomcat-websocket.jar
websocket-api.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

try to import your tag into your JSP file using a directive taglib `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri=""%>`

Comment: As I am using XHTML I'm not sure that is the correct syntax. I have got a 'xmlns:dauct="urn:jspltd:/WEB-INF/tlds/dauct.tld"' entry under jsp:root which I believe performs this same purpose.

Comment: i never worked with XHTML that is why i was recommended that you use this sintax since you are using JSP